# How to hide and not hide cells between columns using VBA-code in excel

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide, multiple-columns

I am new to writing VBA-code and have a little problem.

We are currently conducting a study in where we will receive queastionnaires from participants. There are many "if yes to question 2 please answer question 3 if no please continue to question 4. Once we enter this data in excel each participants answers is given a column. We therefore want the condition written in the VBA-code for one column to apply to the rest of the columns and I cannot get this to work.

The code that works for the B-column is provided below. How do we apply this code so it works for all columns? I.e. how could we first provide participant A's answer in column B and then start all over again when filling out participant B's answers in column C? I have tried several things like loops, "For each column.." and just can't get this together.

Would really appreciate some help!

Thanks.

Elin

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("B3") = 3 Then
        Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
If Range("B5") = 1 Then
        Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
If Range("B7") = 1 Then
        Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
If Range("B9") = 1 Then
        Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
If Range("B18") = 1 Then
        Rows("19:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("19:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
If Range("B19") = 6 Then
        Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are attempting to program a questionnaire in an Excel spreadsheet?  That seems like a very bad tool for the job.  How are you fielding this questionnaire? CATI? Mail/in-person/intercept? Online?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information about the structure of this worksheet. How are the rows/columns arranged? It is not at all clear what you are trying to do -- does each respondent record get a new row? Or is each *question* a row? Etc.  Screenshot/images would help, you can upload to IMGUR.COM and post the links here to help illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    HideUnhide Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    HideUnhide Target
End Sub

Private Sub HideUnhide(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim col As Range
    Set col = Target.Cells(1).EntireColumn
    With Me
        .Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = col.Cells(3).Value <> 3
        .Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = col.Cells(5).Value <> 1
        .Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = col.Cells(7).Value <> 1
        .Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = col.Cells(9).Value <> 1
        .Rows("19:21").EntireRow.Hidden = col.Cells(18).Value <> 1
        .Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = col.Cells(19).Value <> 6
    End With
End Sub
```